# DBSCAN but grouping points that are mutually close?

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, dbscan

I have an adjacency matrix which I am using as my pre detriment distance matrix. Instead of finding all the nearest points of all the nearest points I only want to group points that are all near each-other.

*For example:*

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

# distance matrix (cosine calculated)
adj = np.array([
    [1,1,0,1,0,1,1],
    [1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
    [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [1,0,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
    [1,1,0,0,1,1,1]])

# run through DBSCAN
D_fit = DBSCAN(eps = .99,min_samples=2,metric='precomputed').fit(adj)
print(D_fit.labels_)
```

Normally DBSCAN would group everything together; `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` however if we were to only group points that were all mutually close: `[0 0 1 1 1 2 2]` or `[0 0 1 1 2 2 2]` or `[0 0 1 1 1 0 0]`... This grouping method is what I am looking for. **Is there a tool or package or some way to group points that are all mutually close instead of networked grouping?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient way but this is how I got it to work;

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import random

#set default / starting values
d = len(adj[0])
df_edge= nx.from_numpy_array(adj)
combos = list(nx.enumerate_all_cliques(nx.Graph(df_edge)))
cluster = [-1 for _ in range(d)]
select = random.choice(combos)
c=0

# set cluster value for starting cluster
for i in select:
  cluster[i] = c
c += 1

# continue as long as there are unassigned points
while -1 in cluster:
  # list everything that is ungrouped
  ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(cluster) if x == -1]
  possible = []
  # combine all lists from cobos that don't contain any grouped points.
  for j in combos:
    if all(ele in ind for ele in j) == True:
      possible.append(j)
  # select at random from possible combinations and set as new select value.
  select = random.choice(possible)
  # update cluster list
  for i in select:
    cluster[i] = c
  c += 1
return cluster
```